# Save HTML code in MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, html, save

I am going to save a HTML code base page as my data in MySQL.  Can i do it or I have to save it as a html file and get it again?

Comment: Of course you can store an html file in a database.  You can store any file or string of bytes in a database.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, you can save a HTML file in a database.  Try a `MEDIUMBLOB` or `LONGBLOB` type column.